# SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser returns incorrect/random value

Tags: sharepoint-server, web-part, user-accounts, spcontext

On button click I am saving few values and the user who performed the action by using `SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser` in the list

But `SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser` is not returning the correct user who is currently logged in. Some times it is storing the other user.

My web-part have HTML form with server side button, this form is shared with whole department when user fill few text-boxes and click on button, ideally it should store the current user name, but some times record saved with different username.

```
protected void btnApprove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       using (SPSite siteCol = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
       {
                using (SPWeb web = siteCol.OpenWeb())
                {
                    SPList list = web.Lists["LISTNAME"];
                    SPListItem item = list.GetItemById(Convert.ToInt32(_paramReqId));

                    if (item != null)
                    {

                            item["Approver"] = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser; 
                            item["ApproverTimeStamp"] = DateTime.Now; 
                            item["ApproverOutCome"] = "Approved";
                            item["ApproverComments"] = txtAreaApproverComments.Value;
                            item.Update();
                    }
                }
       }
}
```

EDIT: Item Updated ER code

```
public override void ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        base.ItemUpdated(properties);

        string requestUrl = string.Empty;
        string body = string.Empty;
        SPFieldUserValue Stage1Approver;
        SPFieldUserValue Stage2Approver;

            var context = SPContext.GetContext(properties.Web);

            string requestId = Convert.ToString(properties.ListItem["ID"]);
            SPUser user = new SPFieldUserValue(properties.Web, properties.ListItem["Author"].ToString()).User;
            string email = user.Email;
            string authorName = user.Name;

            string stage1outcome = Convert.ToString(properties.ListItem["Approver1OutCome"]);
            string stage1approverComments = Convert.ToString(properties.ListItem["Approver1ApproverComments"]);

            string stage2outcome = Convert.ToString(properties.ListItem["Approver2OutCome"]);
            string stage2approverComments = Convert.ToString(properties.ListItem["Approver2ApproverComments"]);

            Stage1Approver = new SPFieldUserValue(properties.Web, properties.ListItem["Approver1Approver"].ToString()); 
            Stage2Approver = new SPFieldUserValue(properties.Web, properties.ListItem["Approver2Approver"].ToString()); 


            var company = Convert.ToString(properties.ListItem["Company"]);
            var empName = Convert.ToString(properties.ListItem["EmployeeName"]) != "" ? Convert.ToString(properties.ListItem["EmployeeName"]) : authorName;
            var empCode = Convert.ToString(properties.ListItem["EmployeeCode"]);

            if (stage1outcome == Approved && stage2outcome == "")
            {
                StoreAssignedToUser(Stage2Approver, requestId, context);
            } 
            else if (stage1outcome == Approved && stage2outcome == Approved) 
            {
                CloseRequest(requestId, context)
            } 
        }

    public void StoreAssignedToUser(SPFieldUserValue userfieldvalue, string requestId, SPContext context)
    {
        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(() =>
        {
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite(context.Web.Url.ToString()))
            {
                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                {
                    SPList list = web.Lists["LISTNAME"];
                    SPListItem item = list.GetItemById(Convert.ToInt32(requestId));

                    if (item != null)
                    {
                        item["AssignedTo"] = userfieldvalue;

                        EventFiring eventFiring = new EventFiring();

                        eventFiring.DisableHandleEventFiring();

                        item.Update();

                        eventFiring.EnableHandleEventFiring();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void CloseRequest(string reqId, SPContext context)
    {

            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(() =>
            {
                using (SPSite site = new SPSite(context.Web.Url.ToString()))
                {
                    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                    {
                        SPList list = web.Lists["LISTNAME"];
                        SPListItem item = list.GetItemById(Convert.ToInt32(reqId));

                        if (item != null)
                        {
                            item["RequestStatus"] = "CLOSED";

                            EventFiring eventFiring = new EventFiring();

                            eventFiring.DisableHandleEventFiring();

                            item.Update();

                            eventFiring.EnableHandleEventFiring();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

    }
```

Is there any solid way to do this?

Comment: Why do you re-open `SPSite`/`SPWeb` (`using…`) objects instead of using the current/contextual `SPWeb` all the way?

Comment: Each time I've seen such a weird behavior is when there was additionnal code somewhere, like an event receiver.

Comment: Yes, after saving record. I am triggering Item Updated event.

Comment: Would you share the code of the `Updated` ER?

Comment: @Evariste added ER code.

Comment: the issue is with static variable, I was keeping _paramReqId as static witch creates issue. after declaring local, system is working as expected.

Answer (score -1):

Can you please check with HardCodeed URL in

```
using (SPSite siteCol = new SPSite(**SPContext.Current.Web.Url**))
```

Thanks,
Ani

Comment: I tried, but no help.out of 10 requests it happens once or twice.